# Get Child Item where $_.Name matches Variable

Tags: powershell, datatable, get-childitem

I am pulling information from a query and piping it into a data table. From there I am trying to take each item in my data table and run a `Get-ChildItem` to find the directory location inside a specified folder.

Here is my code...

```
$Query = "SELECT..."
$Results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query 

$Part = $Results[0].immPartID #This will be '01-LX55-001'
$Folder = 'P:\Mech\'

$location = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter *.pdf -Recurse -Force | Where {$_.Name -Match $Part} | Select Directory
$location
```

The issue I am running into is on the last line. If I use `Where {$_.Name -match '01-LX55-001'}` it will find what I need, but if I try and use `Where Name -Match $Part` or `Where {$_.Name -Match $Part}` It will search for a minute but come up with nothing and I am confused because I feel like that should work..

EDIT: I have simplified it down and still when trying to pull the location it does not work...
If I change it to `$location = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter *.pdf -Recurse -Force | Where {$_.Name -Match '01-LX55-001'} | Select Directory` It will work just fine

Comment: Try quoting it `"$part"`.

Comment: Agree with @mklement0 that we need more details. As alternative to your Where-Object clause, have you tried using the filter like `-Filter "*$Part*.pdf"`

Comment: Why the datatable anyway.. Can't you use whatever is in `$Results` straight away like `$Part = @($Results)[0].immPartID` ?

Comment: @Abraham, note that the RHS of a `-match` operation is _implicitly_ stringified, so there's no need for `"$part"`; e.g. `'1 2' -match (1, 2)` is `$true`, because it is equivalent to `'1 2' -match "$(1, 2)"`

Comment: @mklement0, I figured it was a  nested array and quoting it would allow it to be properly matched.

Comment: @Theo That is a very good point I was just trying to organize my query down but you are right I could just get rid of that.. But with the data table removed I still return nothing from get-childitem

Comment: Simply Uncensored, I don't have Sql to test this on, but I'm betting you problem has to do with whatever data type is getting shoved into $Part.  You might try "[string]$Part =" to force it to be a string, or you may have to type cast the data before it goes into $Part.  You also might try "$Part.GetType()" just to find out what it is, probably PSObject, but could be an array.